# Constrained equivalent annotation in hibernate?

Tags: annotations, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

How can I use `constrained` attribute in hibernate annotation onetoone mapping.

I mean what is the equivalent attribute of `constrained` to use in annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Only just seen this, the equivalent annotation is

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
```

Hope this helps. There is more information [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association).

Comment: The answer is ignoring `@OneToOne(optional = false)`.